# Select gender of the in another activity when I click gender type in previous activity

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, sdk, bundle

I am working on a task like this, In first screen I have to choose the gender type of child, then If I select a type that gender should be selected in the another screen as shown in given image of the screen.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5PY7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Store gender type in one string for example

```
String gender-"girl";
```

pass this string in intent for example

```
Intent i=new Intent(currentAtvity.this,nextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("gender",gender);
startActivity(i);
```

now get this value in your next activity:

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
        try {

         String selectedGender=intent.getExtras().getString("gender"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
if(selectedGender.equals("girl")){
//write code to change background of your button or layout
}else{
//boy will be selected
}
```